# Output files not getting uploaded automatically to Storage Container after Task completion when run by Azure RM

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage, azure-rm

When done by C# the files are getting uploaded to Storage Container after "TaskCompletion", but when the same is done in Azure-RM PowerShell, no output files are uploaded to Storage Container even if the Task is successful and output files are generated.

I have taken reference from [Microsoft Docs for Azure RM PowerShell 6.13.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.batch/?view=azurermps-6.13.0#batch). I have tried providing ResourceFiles and OutputFiles as List.
The Resource files are getting downloaded on the Node but after Task completion, the output files aren't getting uploaded.
I have tried changing FilePattern to "*.zip", "Output_00001.zip", but no luck.

I noticed in Batch Explorer that the configuration JSON has empty Output files array when ran by Azure RM. But when run by C# the configuration JSON has output files in it.

```
"resourceFiles": [
    {
      "httpUrl": "https://teststorage.blob.core.windows.net/sku-test/Input_00001.zip?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=iY7lr8QyYzev2Eg1234562BG11ETHftTD8hzZR123456%3D&se=2019-08-26T07%3A10%3A11Z&sp=rwdl",
      "filePath": "Input_00001.zip"
    },
    {
      "httpUrl": "https://teststorage.blob.core.windows.net/sku-test/AppConfig.xml?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=QbSAAsi9gZdU6bS7yoBIvr123456ratH2wC2l123456%3D&se=2019-08-26T06%3A08%3A58Z&sp=r",
      "filePath": "AppConfig.xml"
    },
    {
      "httpUrl": "https://teststorage.blob.core.windows.net/sku-test/Task.ps1?sv=2018-03-28&sr=b&sig=re3Cn8pY4123456DRSt8kn3PHF81FSiJ3zIt7123456%3D&se=2019-08-26T06%3A08%3A58Z&sp=r",
      "filePath": "Task.ps1"
    }
  ],
  "outputFiles": [],
```

When done by C#:

```
"resourceFiles": [
    {
      "autoStorageContainerName": "cdfb56e1-b421-4f06-9ef5-0de18ea288d8",
      "blobPrefix": "AppConfig.config"
    },
    {
      "autoStorageContainerName": "cdfb56e1-b421-4f06-9ef5-0de18ea288d8",
      "blobPrefix": "Task.ps1"
    },
    {
      "autoStorageContainerName": "cdfb56e1-b421-4f06-9ef5-0de18ea288d8",
      "blobPrefix": "Input_00001.zip"
    }
  ],
  "outputFiles": [
    {
      "filePattern": "Output_00001.zip",
      "destination": {
        "container": {
          "containerUrl": "https://teststorage.blob.core.windows.net/cdfb56e1-b421-4f06-9ef5-0de18ea288d8?sv=2018-11-09&sr=c&sig=p2GJGkCmxJAEpJr%2BlwkUTEZjD2GZcGoUpl4Am79YQyM%3D&se=2019-08-25T21%3A32%3A19Z&sp=w"
        }
      },
      "uploadOptions": {
        "uploadCondition": "TaskCompletion"
      }
    }
  ],
```

Here's the PowerShell Script:

```
$uploadOptions = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Batch.Models.PSOutputFileUploadOptions "TaskCompletion";
$OutputSasToken = New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken -Context $StorageContext -Name $StorageContainerName -FullUri -Permission w;
foreach ($blob in $Blobs) {
    $SasToken = New-AzureStorageBlobSASToken -ICloudBlob $blob.ICloudBlob -Context $StorageContext -Permission rwdl -FullUri;
    $blobName = $blob.Name;

    if($blobName.Contains(".zip") -and $blobName.Contains("Input_")) {
        $ResourceFile = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Batch.Models.PSResourceFile -ArgumentList @($SasToken, $blobName);
        $TaskName = "Task_" + $blobName.Replace(".zip", "").Replace("Input_", "");
        $OutputFile = "Output_" + $blobName.Replace("Input_", "");
        $Task = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Batch.Models.PSCloudTask($TaskName, "cmd /S /C `"powershell -f $AppPsFile -configurationFileName $AppConfigFile -inputArchiveName $blobName -outputArchiveName $OutputFile -archiveKey $EncryptionKey");
        $Task.ResourceFiles = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List``1[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Batch.Models.PSResourceFile];
        $Task.ResourceFiles.Add($ResourceFile);
        $Task.ResourceFiles.Add($cResourceFile);
        $Task.ResourceFiles.Add($PsScriptResourceFile);

        $blobContainerDestination = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Batch.Models.PSOutputFileBlobContainerDestination $OutputSasToken;
        $destination = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Batch.Models.PSOutputFileDestination $blobContainerDestination;

        $OutputFileToUpload = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Batch.Models.PSOutputFile $OutputFile, $destination, $uploadOptions;
        $Task.OutputFiles = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List``1[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Batch.Models.PSOutputFile];
        $Task.OutputFiles.Add($OutputFileToUpload);
        $Tasks += @($Task);
    }
}

New-AzureBatchPool -Id $PoolId -VirtualMachineSize $VmSize -VirtualMachineConfiguration $configuration -AutoScaleFormula $AutoScaleFormula -BatchContext $BatchAccount -DisplayName $DisplayName -NetworkConfiguration $networkConfig;
New-AzureBatchJob -Id $JobId -PoolInformation $PoolInformation -BatchContext $BatchAccount;
$Job = Get-AzureBatchJob -BatchContext $BatchAccount -Id $JobId
New-AzureBatchTask -Job $Job -Tasks $Tasks -BatchContext $BatchAccount #Here the tasks are added after Pool, Job are created
```

How can the List of Output files be added?

Comment: I even tried the same in Az PowerShell 2.5, still the same issue :(

Comment: As far as I know, if you want to access one container, you need to read and write permissions. So I think you need to the command ```$OutputSasToken = New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken -Context $StorageContext -Name $StorageContainerName -FullUri -Permission w;``` to ```$OutputSasToken = New-AzureStorageContainerSASToken -Context $StorageContext -Name $StorageContainerName -FullUri -Permission rwl;```

Comment: I have also tried the same, it did not work: `-Permission rwdl`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is a bug in the Azure Batch Powershell module. I've filed a bug on GitHub here (just proxying what you said): https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/9912

As a workaround until the bug is fixed instead of using the `-Tasks` parameter on the `New-AzureBatchTask` cmdlet, you should be able to use the single task options (specifying `New-AzureBatchTask -Job $jobId -ResourceFile @(r1, r2, r3), -OutputFile $OutputFileToUpload ...`) and it should work as expected.

Comment: Yes, the workaround worked - but with a change! Thanks for your help and filing the bug. It was really difficult to figure out the issue in -Tasks and to find the -ResourceFile accepts IDictionary and not array. After so many hits and trial run, I was to create Dictionary[string, string] where the key is the file path, and value is blob source with SAS token - `New-AzBatchTask -Id $SubmitTask.Id -Job $Job -BatchContext $BatchAccount -OutputFile @($OutputFile) -CommandLine $SubmitTask.CommandLine -ResourceFiles $rf`

Another issue is if Tasks count increases, the time to add tasks increases.